# Why aren't Latin "sanguis" and Greek "haima", both meaning "blood", considered to be cognates? Latin word-initial 's' corresponds to Greek 'h'

Tags: etymology, ancient-greek

Why aren't Latin "sanguis" and Greek "haima", both meaning "blood", considered to be cognates? The meaning is, as far as I know, exactly the same. And they sound alike. And Latin word-initial 's' regularly corresponds to Greek 'h'.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. Could you elaborate more on the similarities you find?

Comment: @CannedMan If you think my question is interesting, why don't you upvote it?

Comment: Interesting does not grant upvotes; research effort does. My intention was perhaps not clear, so allow me to elaborate. I find the question interesting in and of itself: If there is a connection between the two words, seeing this proven would allow me to learn more. However, given the state of your question as is, it doesn’t really show ‘research effort’ making it ‘useful and clear’, as the balloon tip for the upvote arrow suggests. Your final point, though I haven’t checked it, could be correct (but no source is provided). But what exactly is it that makes them sound alike to you?

Comment: In other words, I am requesting that you demonstrate more clearly what similarities it is that you actually see, as to me, it is not immediately clear. If there _are_ similarities to be found, that would be interesting indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a complement to Draconis' answer, if you assume they have different suffixes but a common root it's actually possible to get quite close with some finagling but it's ultimately not really possible to account for the *i* in the Greek.
You could try to reconstruct some root *ˣsam-* < *ˣsh₂em-* on the assumption that in Latin the **m* assimilated to the first letter of the suffix *-guin-* (whatever *its* provenance), the only way to smuggle the *-i-* into the Greek is to posit some suffix *ˣ-i̯-* that underwent the same kind of ~metathesis (it's not really metathesis, but the end result is close enough) seen in verbs like φαίνω < **bʰn̥h₂-i̯e-*,τείνω < *ten-i̯e-*, &c., but then you would expect the **m* to become *n* like in βαίνω < **gʷm̥-i̯e-* (and its Latin cognate *venio*).
You might try going further and reduce the root to *ˣseh₂*, which then shows up in the zero-grade in both words, and move the nasal and the Greek *i* out to suffixes as well, and while *ˣsh₂-ei̯-m-* would turn into *haim-* in Greek and *ˣsh₂-em-(gʷ-)* would turn into *san(gu-)* in Latin, at this point you're piling mystery suffix upon mystery suffix and you really have to start wondering what you're even doing.

*Sanguis* becomes much more tractable when you connect it to ἔαρ instead, not least because the Hittite cognate *ešḫar* was a heteroclitic r/n-stem (meaning it ended in *-r-* in some cases and in *-(e)n-* in others; it's a pattern that goes back to PIE and can also be seen in e.g. Latin *iecu**r*** 'liver', gen. *ieci**n**oris*, though that's been somewhat mangled), nicely accounting for the *n* in *sanguis*. This still leaves *-guin-*, in which people have seen the root **ǵʰeu̯-* 'to pour' (as in Greek χεύω, Latin *fundō*) and some additional noun suffix *-(e)n-*, which shows up in a lot of places.
This adds up to a reconstructible form **h₁sh₂-en-ǵʰu̯-n̥-s* (without getting too deep into why the laryngeals need to be there; **h₁* is there largely for structural reasons, **h₂* to account for the *a* that shows up in languages where that's meaningful), which is a very plausible construction that turns into Latin *sanguis* with, AFAICT, perfect regularity.

Whatever αἷμα's actual etymology, you cannot derive it from **h₁(e)sh₂-*: even in the zero-grade the resulting word would have to start with ε, so the **s* would be intervocalic and you'd end up with smooth breathing.

(Latin actually also likely had an exact cognate for ἔαρ in *assyr*, an unusually spelled word that only shows up in Paul the Deacon's epitome of Festus' mostly lost epitome of Verrius Flaccus' lost *De verborum significatione*.)

Comment: I think *\*h₁sh₂-en-ǵʰu̯-n̥-s* would yield ἤμφας in Attic FWIW.

Comment: "... *assyr*, an unusually spelled word that only shows up in Paul the Deacon's epitome of Festus' mostly lost epitome of Verrius Flaccus' lost *De verborum significatione*" — I love this.

Comment: Could you add a parenthetical remark explaining what zero-grade is?

Comment: @CannedMan While I always try to provide googleable keywords, answers like this are by their nature never going to be perfectly accessible to everyone. If someone doesn't know what a zero-grade is in the context of PIE (and I fully accept that obviously most people don't), they lack so much relevant background that just explaining that little thing really isn't going to make a meaningful difference for them.

Answer (score 8):

The initial consonants correspond, but the rest of the word does not. Latin *san(guin)-* seems to go back to something like **h₁sh₂-en-*, which we also see in Hittite *išḫan-* and Sanskrit *asna-* with the same meaning. The original nominative was **h₁esh₂-r-*, as seen in Hittite *ešḫar* and Sanskrit *asṛj* (and Old Latin *assyr*); in Greek, this became a different word for blood, ἔαρ.

The etymology of the Latin word is somewhat unclear and almost certainly involved analogy and possibly Etruscan influence; the etymology of αἷμα is likewise unclear. But there's no obvious reason why *-im-* would correspond to *-nguin-*. One consonant lining up isn't enough to make things cognate.

Comment: If one consonant and the exact same meaning isn't enough to make a cognate, why are English "tooth" and German "Zahn" considered cognates?

Comment: @FlatAssembler Because we see systematic correspondences between the other parts as well. German /an/ regularly corresponds to (pre-GVS) English /o:/, for example.